# Any tool to highlight collocations

Tags: collocations

It is believed that learning collocations is an effective way to enhance fluency. I wonder if there are any tools that, when provided with a text, can highlight its collocations? It would be great if it also can show degrees of words cohesion using different highlight colors.

Comment: Requests for resources are off-topic (see https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) We have a [Resources](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/735/) list on our meta site that might help, or if you're looking for a software recommendation, you might try [softwarerecs.se].